# CRM 2011 Multiple Instances on Same SQL Server

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We need to install multiple deployments of CRM 2011 for different clients. Is it possible to have a single SQL Server with multiple named instances as the database server - or - do we need a single SQL Server per CRM installation?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Named instances are fine for Dynamics CRM. However, do you really need separate instances of SQL?

Are you aware of the multi-tenant capabilities of Dynamics CRM? You could create as many organizations on a single SQL-Server, as long your infrastructure has enough resources. Each of the organizations are completely isolated from each other.

Comment: Thanks ccellar.  I wasn't sure so your answer really help clarify things for me.  Thank you.